# Returning Data from XML file with Multiple NameSpaces C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I am having trouble returning data from a Linq to XML query. 
I have the following XML

```
<sdnList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>03/14/2013</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>5440</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
</sdnList>
```

I am trying to get the value of Publish Date using the following

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
XNamespace xNS = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd";
XNamespace xNS1 = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
string strCurrentDate = xDoc.Element(xNS1 + sdnList").Element("publshInformation").Element("Publish_Date").Value;
```

This just returns an object expected error.
I know my problem is around the namespaces (and most likely is will be a simple solutions)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the elements in that document are in the `http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd` namespace, so you need something like

```
xDoc.Element(xNS + "sdnList")
    .Element(xNS + "publshInformation")
    .Element(xNS + "Publish_Date").Value;
```

Comment: Perfect. I knew it would be simple. Thanks.

Comment: @smitchelluk the way to remember it is that whenever you see an unprefixed element name in the XML, look "up the tree" to find the nearest `xmlns="..."` on the element itself, its parent, grandparent, etc.  If you reach the root without finding an `xmlns="..."` then the element is not in a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
XNamespace xNS = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd";
string strCurrentDate = xDoc.Element(xNS + "publshInformation").Element(xNS + "Publish_Date").Value;
```